# How to write an algorithm to construct numbers from items in array

Tags: c++, algorithm

Edit: I have sorted array in descending order (a[0] is the largest)

```
int [n] a;  (n_max = 18)
```

each item in the array has an integer with value range: 0 -> 9.
I want to construct **2 groups of numbers** from the item in the array such that:

```
//group A: 
numberA[0] = a[0]*pow(10,0);
numberA[1] = a[0]*pow(10,1) + a[1]*pow(10,0);
numberA[2] = a[0]*pow(10,2) + a[1]*pow(10,1) + a[2]*pow(10,0);
numberA[3] = a[0]*pow(10,3) + a[1]*pow(10,2) + a[2]*pow(10,1) + a[3]*pow(10,0);
numberA[n] = a[0]*pow(10,n-1) +...+ a[n-1]*pow(10,0)

//group B: 
numberB[0] = a[0]*pow(10,0);
numberB[1] = a[0]*pow(10,0) + a[1]*pow(10,1);
numberB[2] = a[0]*pow(10,0) + a[1]*pow(10,1) + a[2]*pow(10,2);
numberB[3] = a[0]*pow(10,0) + a[1]*pow(10,1) + a[2]*pow(10,2) + a[3]*pow(10,3);
numberA[n] = a[0]*pow(10,0) +...+ a[n-1]*pow(10,n-1)
```

For example if I have an array[4] = {9,8,7,6};
I would have the following numbers: numberA[] = {9 ,98 ,987, 9876} and numberB = {6, 76, 876, 9876}

Could anyone educate me with some algorithms using for loop, recursive or anything witty and also the time + space complexity of it ?

My attempt so far:

```
long long int numberA = 0;
vector<long long int>numberAList; 
numberA = num[0]*(pow(10,0));
numberAList.push_back(numberA);
numberA = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++ ){               // complexity: O(logn) & this algorithm is wrong
    for (int j = i+1; j<n-1; j++){
        numberA += num[i]*pow(10,n-1-j);
        cout<<"numberA"<<numberA<<endl;
    }
    numberAList.push_back(numberA);
}

for (int i = 0; i < (n-2); i++ ){
    cout<<numberAList[i]<<" ";
}
```

After suggestion from user1984. I made the codes:

```
long long int numberA=0;
vector<long long int> numberAList;
for (int i = 0; i < n-1 ; i++ ){                  // complexity O(n)
    numberA *= 10;
    numberA += num[i];
    cout<<i<<", numberA: "<<numberA<<endl;
    numberAList.push_back(numberA);
}

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++ ){
    cout<<numberAList[i]<<" ";
}

long long int numberB = 0;
vector<long long int> numberBList;                        
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){                           // complexity O(n)
    int j = i+1;
    if (j<n){
        for (j ; j<n; j++ ){
            numberB += num[j]*(pow(10,n-j-1));
        }
        numberBList.push_back(numberB);
        numberB=0;
    }
}

cout<<"numberBlist: "<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++ ){
    cout<<numberBList[i]<<" ";
}
```

The code works ok with short numbers; however, with large number, I start to see some weird results, even after I changed the data type to long long int.

Could anyone help?

```
// if input = 94321

numberBlist:
94321 4321 321 21 1
numberAlist:
9 94 943 9432 94321

// but with input = 999999999999999999
numberBlist:
100000000000000016 10000000000000000 999999999999999 99999999999999 9999999999999 999999999999 99999999999 9999999999 999999999 99999999 9999999 999999 99999 9999 999 99 9
numberAlist:
9 99 999 9999 99999 999999 9999999 99999999 999999999 9999999999 99999999999 999999999999 9999999999999 99999999999999 999999999999999 9999999999999999 99999999999999999
```

Comment: If you have an `array[5]` it contains 5 elements, not 4. Btw, are you aware of that `^` means xor? It looks like you want a power function there instead.

Comment: [`std::partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) with appropriate custom operator should do the job.

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself to learn, start with a simple loop from `0` to `n - 1` (inclusive). Then add calculation for the current expression in the loop and print its result. Then add a new variable (initialized to zero) and add the result of the calculation to that variable. Then after the loop print the value of the summation variable.

Comment: Avoid [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) with non floating point numbers (rounding problems).

Comment: *"The time and space complexity for this is just log(n)"*. No it is linear (`O(n)`)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an assignment, so I'm not going to provide code, but a (hopefully), clear approach that helps you to solve the problem in whatever language you prefer.

1. Have a variable `current` that tracks the current value you are at
2. Have an array `res` to accumulate the results as you iterate over the input array, `nums`.
3. For each `nums_i` in the array `nums`, do the following, respecting the order:

- `current *= 10`
- `current += nums_i`
- push current onto `res`

That's it. I think the approach is self explanatory, but if you feel it needs more elaboration, please ask.

**Update based on OP's recent edit:**
To deal with arbitrary size integers you have 2 options:

1. Use a library that handles arbitrary sized number arithmetic, like [gmplib](https://gmplib.org/), and go with an algorithm like the one you currently have or a similar one.
2. Use the fact that you don't change the base of the number and employ string/char concatenation. If you need to convert it to an integer at the end, you can use a library. Note that these libraries use bit manipulation techniques and have been optimized to work very fast. Read for example [this informative article](https://johnnylee-sde.github.io/Fast-numeric-string-to-int/) for details.

A note on the test you ran on large numbers: "999999999999999999" is smaller than a 64 bit signed integer, so the current algorithm shouldn't have worked since a "long long" in c++ is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits. I'm not much familiar with c++ but, since not all the parts of the code are shared, look if you have a place where you are storing that large value in some smaller data type that may overflow.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion. It is just 2 steps work. Log(n)

Comment: hi @user1984: would you help with the case of very large number ?

Comment: For large numbers do it as string processing.

Comment: read my update @MinhPham

Answer (score 2):

With [`std::partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum), you might do

```cpp
std::vector<int> nums{9, 8, 7, 6};
std::vector<int> res(nums.size());
std::partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(),
                 res.begin(),
                 [](int acc, int n){ return 10 * acc + n; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8af7afd283e78124)